# Issue after restarting Feltzin System race

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-going-commando

I'm playing Ratchet and Clank 2 (Going Commando) on the PS3 and have run into an issue while trying to get the platinum bolt in the Feltzin System. The one where you need to get all 50 rings in the race and you'll get the platinum bolt on the last ring.

I crashed into an asteroid and restarted the challenge. When I start over, all the rings disappeared and the time is stuck at 00.00.00.

I've already searched Google, but I can't find anything. Is that a bug? Will I need to reset the entire game just for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that reseting your system (ps3) is a possible solution for this problem. At least worked for me.